# unitary element and *-homomorphism

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

This is a follow up question on [About unitary element in a $C^*$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4091025/about-unitary-element-in-a-c-algebra)

> Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra.
> Let $\pi: A \rightarrow A/I$ be the canonical *- homomorphism, where $I$ is a closed ideal of A
> Let $u \in A/ I$ be unitary and $\sigma(u) = \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{T}: Re(\lambda) \geq 0\}$, where $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle.
> Show that there exists some unitary $x \in A$ such that $\pi(x) =u$.

> For any general unitary $u$, if $\pi: B(H) \rightarrow B(H)/K(H)$, can we still get a unitary $x$ such that $\pi(x) =u$? ''

I tried to do it following Mike's hints.

I know that by Theorem 2.12 in Murphy, since $\sigma(u) \ne \mathbb{T}$, there exists a self-adjoint $a$ such that $e^{ia}$.
Since the $\pi$ is surjective, there exists $x \in A$ such that $\pi(x) = e^{ia}$. Now below is that part I'm not sure about.

Since $a$ is self-adjoint, we have that there exists some self-adjoint $k \in A $ such that $\pi(e^{ik}) = e^{ia}$. So we've found a unitary $e^{ik}$.

Could someone please let me know if the above claim is correct? If so, how is that true? If not, how do I continue with this proof?

For the second part,
I know that by Atkinson's Theorem of $\pi$ we have that $\pi(u)$ is invertible. By a Fredholm argument, we have that $\pi(u) \ne \pi(w)$ for any invertible $w$. From here I'm not sure how to continue. I might be completely off...

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have that $u=e^{ia}$, find some $k\in A$ such that $\pi(k)=a$.  Then it follows from continuity of $\pi$ that $\pi(e^{ik})=u$.

The issue with your second question is indeed an issue of Fredholm index (or more generally, an issue arising from K-theory).  If $y\in B(H)$ is a Fredholm operator with index $\neq 0$, and $u=\pi(y)$ is a unitary, then any lift of $u$ is a Fredholm operator with the same index as $y$, hence cannot be a unitary, as all unitary (invertible) operators have index $0$.

Comment: Why we can find  the Fredholm operator $y$ with index $\ne 0$? What is a lift of $u$? Also, why we can conclude that $y$ is not unitary? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and $y$ is the operator $(y\xi)(n)=\xi(n+1)$, then $y$ is Fredholm with $\operatorname{index}(y)=1\neq0$.  By a lift of $u$ I mean an operator $v\in B(H)$ such that $\pi(v)=u$.  And $y$ cannot be unitary, because unitaries have Fredholm index $0$, while we specified that the index of $y$ was nonzero.

Comment: I see that $\pi(y)$ is invertible. Why is it unitary? Thank you so much!

Comment: And one last question: Why any lift of $u$ will have the same index as $y$? Is it because $\pi$ is a *- homomorphism? Thank you!

Comment: For the shift operator $y$ in my comment, it's readily verified that $yy^*=1$ and $y^*y=1-p$, where $p$ is a rank-one projection.  Hence $\pi(y^*y)=1-\pi(p)=1=\pi(yy^*)$, so $\pi(y)$ is a unitary.

Comment: The fact that any lift of $u$ has the same index as $y$ is a result in Fredholm theory:  if $u_1,u_2$ are Fredholm operators and $u_1-u_2$ is compact, then $\operatorname{index}(u_1)=\operatorname{index}(u_2)$.  This can be found in Murphy's book for example.